# Selenium webdriver.Remote cannot connect to http://localhost:9999

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was writing a code to automate desktop applications. I saw from the internet that selenium could be used to automate desktop applications using webdriver.Remote(). I am trying to automate the calculator. But while trying to open the calculator I am getting the WinError 10061.The error message and the code is given below.

```
from selenium import webdriver

#initialising driver to open the calculator
driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://localhost:9999',
            desired_capabilities={
                "debugConnectToRunningApp": 'false',
                "app": r"C:/windows/system32/calc.exe"
            })
```

But this code gave an error that

**urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9999): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000294BF4AB6A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))**

I have tried disabling the firewall but it did not help. How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What exactly would be running on your local machine at port ```9999```?

Comment: I want to run the calculator application at localhost

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you copied the code from [here](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/issues/299), which means that to run your code, you must have launched [Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/releases) first. Personally, I'm wary of a programme that hasn't been updated since 2016.